# Django: Foreign Keys and Model Relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have three model classes. Say Image, People and Location.
There are multiple people per location and each person can have multiple images.
Every Location is represented by an image.

I have Image - location(field) foreign key to Location and Location - image(field) foreign key to Image. 
I know this is circular. And will throw an erroe. What would the alternative be/ a viable solution?

EDIT: People can have multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OneToOneField` seen here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield

The alternative is to remove the foreign key from the `Image` to the `Location` since I'm guessing you will usually be grabbing the image from the location and not the other way around (switch it if I'm wrong).  You will then have to resolve the reverse relationship as a list of referencing objects, rather than a unique object.  Using `ForeignKey(unique=True)` may also solve this issue.

Edit:
Try removing all foreign key references from image.  Use OneToOneField from the `Location` to `Image`.  Then, use a ForeignKey from `Person` to `Image`.  Don't put foreign keys in image.  You can still access the reverse relationships given an image.

Comment: I actually started writing out the `ForeignKey(unique=True)` idea, and realized half-way through that there's a problem with it: there's nothing stopping a person and a location from having the same image, which is presumably not what he wants. `OneToOneField` has the same problem (it's just shorthand for FK unique=True), which is why I edited it out of my response. Really, the issue is that he either needs zero image tables (and image data in each person/location) or two image tables (one to serve each purpose). My vote is for zero tables.

Comment: people and locations can have the same image. Sorry. Please look at my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    [...]

class Location(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)  # or use OneToOneField if every location has a unique image
    [...]

class Person(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    [...]
```

Comment: people and locations can have the same image. Sorry. Please look at my edits